# Overvoltage i/o pin fried my arduino uno. Can it be saved?

Tags: arduino

I accidently put 12V into one of the i/o pins and fried the board bad enough to go through the usb and shut off my laptop.  Is the whole board junk now or just the atmega?

Comment: Which pin? Can you point it out on a schematic?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming it doesn't work as is, now -- right?

Comment: The on light works and the SMD led on 13 is on.  I had 12,13 hooked up to the breadboard so it would be one of those.

Comment: I don't know what any of that means without a schematic.

Comment: Please be careful testing the board. You wouldn't be the first, or last, who has broken a development board and then managed to break a PC trying to get it working. USB can be quite sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to definitively say, but I wouldn't be surprised if the whole thing is toast. There are a few things you can do to check. Look over the board for any visible scorch marks or popped caps, anything physically damaged.

With the atmega removed, plug the board in. You might try plugging it into something other than your laptop to start with. Something with a solid 5V output, like a wall to USB charger for a cell phone. There's enough other stuff on the Uno that, even without the Atmega, you should be able to discern whether things are working properly. Get a multimeter and probe around testing voltages. Make sure that +5V pins are actually at +5V and +3.3V pins are correct as well. Feel the board (carefully) and make sure nothing is hot. That's a sure sign that things aren't going well.

If that turns out okay, go ahead and plug the board into your laptop without the Atmega. Check if your Arduino IDE or any serial terminal program can still recognize the COM port. If it does, I'd say you're **probably** in luck and the board may be ok.

Lastly, if everything is successful, you can try putting the Atmega back in. I wouldn't hold my breath about it working, but it isn't unheard of that just a single I/O is fried.

Comment: The 5V and 3.3V pins are good.  The Arduino IDE doesn't recognize it anymore though.

Comment: When you plug in the arduino, does it create a new COM port, if so, then you just need a new ATMega328P like this: http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9061 Otherwise, if it doesn't create a new COM port when plugging it in, the FTDI and who knows what else is fried. Unless your time is worthless, it'll be cheaper to buy a new Arduino

Comment: There's no FTDI on an Uno, which replaces that part from previous designs with a second smaller atmega having a hardware USB interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's most likely that you've fried your atmega, everything else is probably OK.  Try what bjthom suggested and if the FTDI chip is OK, then you're probably OK to replace the atmega.  Get one of [these pre-programmed chips](https://www.adafruit.com/products/123) from Adafruit or similar and pop it in, everything should be OK.

While you're at it you can get some cheaper non-programmed ATMega328P-20PU chips from a variety of places and load the ArduinoISP example sketch from the sketchbook and use that to program the Arduino bootloader onto some spares in case this happens again.  They're pretty cheap, and as you can see if you burn up a chip and don't have any way to program the Arduino bootloader onto an new chips, you're out some extra money and time.

Comment: Thanks,  Those aren't much more than the blank chips. I do have an Arduino mega that's being used in my 3D printer.  I might take that out and use it to burn a bootloader on my spare atmega chip.

Answer (score 0):

CMOS does not like having a voltage applied to signal pins greater outside the supply rails. It causes the "Crowbar effect"

If the protection diodes fry open then the chip turns into an SCR and latches a short across the supply, which in turn shuts off the supply if it creates an undervoltage (UVP cct) It is sometimes recoverable as long as traces and diodes and chips dont have enough time to smoke.  A complete power down (battery removal) is only needed to drop the standby voltage in this case if it is involved with the circuit affected.

Comment: All the traces look good to me and I can't find anything visibly wrong with any components.  I think there may have been a bit of smoke when it happened though.

Comment: does the USB port still work?

Answer (score 0):

Prior advice is mostly good.

For future reference - I have had an extreme case where about 150 VDC was shorted into a piece of equipment (a long ago D2 development kit) which has two PCBs and dozens of TTL and MOS parts. I had a second identical system and all the ICs were socketed! I marked the suspect ICs visually so there would be no mistakes and then swapped in all the ICs from the working system. The "dead" system worked. I then progressively swapped back the suspect ICs testing operation after each swap. A number of ICs were thus identified as dead and replacing them restored operation.

What was interesting was that all the "power" ICs died and none of the non-power ines did. Anything that had a port intended to sink or source 10+ mA or so died. Gate ICs and similar didn't. As I recall (30+ years on :-) ) it was quite a consistent boundary test for dead or alive. Whether this is useful generally or in your case I don't know, BUT if you were desoldering devices it may provide a guide to which ones to try first.

---

If any supply bus is hard short (5V, 3V3) check tantalum caps, which go VERY hard short when invited.